# Getting "Managed Package Patch Modification" Exception - when nothing has been modified

Tags: managed-package, lightning-aura-components, deployment, migration-tool, patch

We are getting the following error when attempting to deploy an UN-changed version of an `AuraDefinitionBundle` to one of our Patch orgs using the Force.com Migration Tool:

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Managed Package Patch Modification Exception: A
>   change was made to the patch release that will change the visible
>   behavior of the application: You can't delete managed-released
>   components in a patch release

This is only happening when trying to deploy one of our `AuraDefinitionBundle` files. We have not made any changes to any portions of this bundle at all, so we are very confused why we are getting this error, and it is causing our automated Continuous Integration builds to this patch org to fail.

As proof that we have not modified anything in this file, we retrieved the file exactly as it is from the org, then redeployed it unchanged. That is, we used the Force.com Migration Tool's `ant retrieveUnpackaged` default command with a `package.xml` like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>SomeBundleName</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

And then immediately used `ant deployUnpackaged` to deploy what was retrieved right back to the same org. And we got the above error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try saving each components one by one to discover which component is failing .Lightning is still evolving so something might have broken some of the components .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I know exactly which component is failing. The component I'm trying to retrieve / deploy unchanged is the only one that is failing.

Comment: Is it compiling atleast when you try to save ?

Comment: @zachelrath did you every resolve this issue?  Have the *exact* same issue in a patch org of ours.

Comment: @StephenRoden Nope, we submitted a case but Partner Support closed the issue as being "Out of Scope". We circumvented the issue by excluding that file from our CI deployment to the particular patch org --- since the file was unmodified it was not a problem to exclude it. But this approach is obviously unsustainable.

Comment: @zachelrath Ended up excluding it from CI/deploy too. Little bit further in terms of Partner Support however ... kinda ... sorta ... not really. Got it to the R&D level who logged it as a bug.

Comment: @StephenRoden Well, it's gratifying to hear that it got acknowledged as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce acknowledged that this is a bug on their Known Issues site, which is "In Review" as of July 29, 2016:

[Salesforce Known Issue: "You can't delete managed-released components in a patch release" error when AuraDefinitionBundle which isn't modified is deployed to patch org](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000017wrYQAQ)